# Etymology of sh*tfaced?

Tags: etymology, offensive-language

Where does the term *shitfaced* come from? I'm aware that it means to be totally drunk, but I'm not sure how *shitfaced* describes being drunk.

Comment: Entomology = study of insects.

Comment: whoops, my bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Wordorigins.org](http://www.wordorigins.org/index.php/forums/viewthread/540/) the theory is as follows...

> 1960s student slang according to etymology online.  Some sites suggest that it’s origin might be from being so drunk that your face is in or near a toilet.  I don’t think that can be assumed as fact, however.

Not sure how true it is, as such expressions are seldom tracked.

Comment: That is basically how it was explained to me in the 70's

Comment: I always though it meant your face was flush, as if working hard while sitting upon a toilet.  Ergo, TOILet.  ;)